# Consume ASP.Net Web Service using ColdFusion

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion

Here is what I have so far. I am creating an ASP.NET Web service to log our internal web site activities. The majority of our internal sites are written in ColdFusion. I have used web services before in the ASP.Net world, but ColdFusion is a little new to me. I am just starting to experiment with this type of situation. As an explanation to why we are mixing the two technologies: we are moving away from ColdFusion at this time and are in a transitional phase.

The C# code is first. This I believe is correct.

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://oursite.org:86")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class LogEvent : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private IContainer components = null;


    public LogEvent()
    {
        InitalizeComponent();
    }

    private void InitalizeComponent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && components != null)
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }



    [WebMethod]
    public string InsertEvent()
    {

        return "HellWorld";

    }
}
```

I have just a simple CFC to call the web service.

```
<cffunction name="TestWebService" access="remote" returntype="Any" >

        <cfinvoke webservice="oursite.org:86/LogEvent.asmx?wsdl" method="InsertEvent" returnvariable="result"   >

        <cfdump var="#result#">       
  </cffunction>
```

When I run the CFC method I get the following error back.

```
Unable to read WSDL from URL:
```

I have searched and followed every tutorial and suggestion I have found, but I am not an expert at ColdFusion. Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting `http://` in front of the URL? I don't know if ColdFusion will parse the URL without it.

Comment: Yes, I think I tried it without just to see if it would work.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion? And what kind of WSDL is being produced by .NET? I think the choices are "RPC" or "Document" style. Review what kinds of WSDLs your CF version is capable of reading. I've run into this issue in the past with older versions of CF not supporting newer WSDL specs.

Comment: I am running CF9 and the .NET version is 4.0. I thought the same thing at first and tried an older version of .NET. Then I figured out the cloud server issue and everything worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I completely spaced that the ColdFusion Server is a cloud server (i.e. not in our network) and the Web Service is running on a local network server. Once I moved the ColdFusion code to a local server the service worked like it was suppose to.